# How can I state having a "seat at the table" in a more assertive way, like claiming a seat?

Tags: expressions

I would like to make it known that I have a "seat at the table," but I would like to state that in a more proactive fashion, like, to take a seat, or claim a seat.  Is there an efficient way of saying this?  Or, is there a better phrase? Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually mean a ~seat~ or do you mean, "I'm part of the negotiations"  "a seat at the table" has idiomatic suggestions to it in terms of claiming decision making power.  But if you were going up to a table at a banquet ... the "I have a reserved seat" is correct.

Comment: I meant "part of the negotiations."

Comment: Assertive has many shades but if you want to make it clear that you're a player in the discussion - not just an invitee perhaps:  "I ~expect~ a seat at the table".  That -is- very direct but "seat at the table" is already tempered; it implies you're participating, not dictating.You can temper a little bit more with some cheery informality perhaps:  "The meeting sounds like a great idea, I'll expect a seat at the table."  You might even take more "ownership" by expanding the conversation to. "Who else should we invite?", indirectly claiming a central decision making role in the process.

Comment: To be more assertive, tell it like it is? : "This decision will effect my department and performance directly and I expect to be involved with all discussions involving the issue" ? Claiming it is ~your responsibility~ to be involved that way keeps it from being a personal demand. Its not a matter of "being left out", its a matter of doing your job ?  (just my 2cents... If your boss is a sociopath/insecure who likes to fire people who voice strong opinions, please disregard LOL)

Comment: This question is off-topic here, but please consider [joining the Interpersonal Skills site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92736/interpersonal-skills)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the term **[reserved](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reserve)**. It's formal and assertive, and it suits your intended meaning:

> to keep something for a particular person, purpose, or situation

Here's a simple, short sentence that conveys your idea:

> I've reserved a seat at the table.

Note that this version is slightly ambiguous in that it doesn't specify *for whom* you've reserved the seat (you could have very well reserved it for a friend or loved one, for instance). If you want to be really explicit, say:

> I've reserved a seat at the table for myself.

Comment: I think the OP meant ["a position as a member of a group that makes decisions"](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/a-seat-at-the-table) (not necessarily literally "a seat at the table"). I could very well be wrong.